# HTTP Status 404 - No handler mapping found

Tags: spring, jsp

Having some issues while running the below code:

Web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">

        <display-name>To do List</display-name>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>login.do</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/todo-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

--------------    todoservlet.xml -------------

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.in28minutes" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix">
                <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
            </property>
            <property name="suffix">
                <value>.jsp</value>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>

    </beans>
```

--------------    login.jsp  -------------

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><font color="red">${errorMessage}</font></p>
        <form action="login.do" method="POST">
            Name : <input name="name" type="text" /> 
            Password : <input name="password" type="password" /> 
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

--------------    Controller -------------

```
    package com.in28minutes.login;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes("name")
    public class LoginController {

        @Autowired
        private LoginService loginService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showLoginPage() {
            return "login";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String handleUserLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name,
                @RequestParam String password) {
            if (!loginService.validateUser(name, password)) {
                model.put("errorMessage", "Invalid Credentials");
                return "login";
            }
            model.put("name", name);
            return "welcome";
        }
    }
```

--------------   getting error message  -------------

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/in28Minutes27-springmvc/

------------browser error --------------

    HTTP Status 404 - 


    type Status report

    message 

    description The requested resource is not available.


    Apache Tomcat/8.0.39

----------------- log on console ---------------------


    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,152 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@df024db
    DEBUG   2016-12-20 12:14:32,153 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/in28Minutes27-springmvc/]
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,155 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping@1a6fbdb3] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    DEBUG   2016-12-20 12:14:32,156 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Looking up handler method for path /login.do
    DEBUG   2016-12-20 12:14:32,156 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Did not find handler method for [/login.do]
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,157 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping@24b1f9e9] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,158 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping  - No handler mapping found for [/login.do]
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,158 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@1f358bf7] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,159 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  - No handler mapping found for [/login.do]
    WARN    2016-12-20 12:14:32,159 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/in28Minutes27-springmvc/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,159 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@df024db
    DEBUG   2016-12-20 12:14:32,159 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - Successfully completed request
    TRACE   2016-12-20 12:14:32,159 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Publishing event in WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/in28Minutes27-springmvc/]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcher]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[23ms]; status=[OK]
```

I am not able to resolve this issues; any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please explain your question so people might be interested to answer it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your web.xml file. You cannot use .do extension as a welcome file, It should be valid presentation file with extension i.e .html, .jsp etc

Replace below block of code in your web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Hope it will work for you.

**More Details:**
when you don't have any handler methods to handle that path. Add one. Or add a `<welcome-file>` to your deployment descriptor, ie. the web.xml.

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

assuming the index.jsp is at the root of the WAR, ie. outside WEB-INF.